# Fragment navigation on back button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have a fragment which has a context menu which in turn calls another fragment:

```
switch (item.getItemId())
            {
 case MENU_EDIT:
                 FragmentTransaction ft =getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                 PlayListDetailsView fragment=new PlayListDetailsView();
                 //fragment.getArguments().putLong("id", (Long)info.id);
                 ft.add(android.R.id.content, fragment);
                 ft.attach(fragment);
                 ft.commit();
}
```

The new fragment opens alright, but once i press back the app totally exits withour going back to the fragment it was called from.
Also the commented line of an attempt to add a bundle information fails and cannot be retrieved in the fragment called
Suggest a fix please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to call [addToBackstack()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29) before calling commit.

Comment: Yep, thats what i missed. Thanks Sujith

Answer (score 2):

First of all fragments should communicate through activity, not directly: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

As for your question:

1. For back key to work properly, you should add transaction to back stack, put this before commit:

   ```
   ft.addToBackStack("playlistdetails");
   ```
2. Arguments should be added like this:

   ```
   Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.putLong("id", (Long)info.id);
   fragment.setArguments(args);
   ```